# Pasar los items de un treepanel a un html editor SENCHA 4.2

Tags: html, c#, extjs

La pregunta es como puedo pasar en formato texto, sin perdida de jerarquías, de un treepanel a un html editor

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Asi es como se llena el `treepanel`

```
var arbolActividad = Ext.getCmp('trp_ArbolActividad');
                            store = arbolActividad.getStore();
                            store.setRootNode(request.proxy.reader.jsonData.results[0].xml_arbol);
                            arbolActividad.expandAll();
```

Y esta es la forma en la que pretendo tomar sus **items**, pero solo devuelve `[object]`:

```
var editorHTML = Ext.getCmp('txt_Comentario');
                            editorHTML.setValue(arbolActividad.getDockedItems());
```

**¿Alguna función que pueda hacer esto?**

Comment: ¿qué es lo que pretendes lograr con esto?

Comment: solo quiero plasmar el texto del treepanel al htmleditor

Comment: esto para que se envié en un formulario como texto del htmleditor